# Expanding parameters inside \csname

Tags: macros

I've browsed every question I can find on `\csname` and I see lots of code that uses it inside a macro and passes the arguments inside to be part of the name, but only when defining a macro. I need to use it for calling a macro.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\other}{pass}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\csname #1 \endcsname}
\newcommand{\anothertest}[1]{\expandafter\csname #1 \endcsname}

\begin{document}

\test{other}
\anothertest{other}
I see nothing.

\end{document}
```

This should be calling `\other twice`, yes? But when I compile it with pdflatex, it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Alternatively, is there another way to accomplish the following:
My code defines a series of `\callme` commands: `\callmeFrank`, `\callmeAnne`. Inside my text, I want to be able to dynamically call those from within another macro (that does a lot of other stuff too). `\newcommand{\BigFunction}[1]{dostuff\csname\callme#1\endcsname}do more stuff}`. Obviously, this isn't working for me, as shown by the MWE above.

Comment: The two commands do the same thing, because `\expandafter` in the second one just tries to expand the first token in `#1`, which in the example happens to be `o` (so nothing happens). You see nothing because when `\csname ...\endcsname` is used and the resulting command doesn't exist, it's defined to be the same as `\relax`, which is the case here because `\other` isn't defined.

Comment: You probably want `\csname callme#1\endcsname`, so when `#1` is `Frank` you get the same as if you had typed `\callmeFrank`.

Comment: Except that the resulting command *is* defined. I defined `\other`. As for your second comment, I tried `\csname callme#1 \endcsname` and it was giving nothing. Thus, my original question.

Comment: `#1 \endcsname` has a space, thus you are calling `\other•` where `•` is a space in the macro name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\other}{pass}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\anothertest}[1]{\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\test{other}
\anothertest{other}
I see \emph{something}.

\end{document}
```

You have a space in `#1 \endcsname` which means that you are calling macros with a trailing space *in the name*. You defined `\other`, *not* `\other•`. Then it results in a `\relax`. If you remove the space it should compile fine.

Comment: the `\expandafter` isn't doing anything here

Comment: Manuel: Thanks. I saw spaces in other examples, and emulated them.

Comment: @JKreft As David says, the `\expandafter` is useless there, since everything between `\csname` and `\endcsname` is expanded before creating the token. What did you want to achieve?